# Why is the JSON not written?

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is code:

```java
public static void init() {
    File file = new File(SimpleMessagesAPI.getMainAPI().getDataFolder(), "config.json");
    try {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        ObjectNode firstObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        ObjectNode secondObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();

        firstObjectNode.put("period", 5);
        firstObjectNode.put("async", true);
        firstObjectNode.put("country", "Europe/Bucharest");

        secondObjectNode.putArray("broadcast")
                .add("&7Hello players! Now is %server_online players!")
                .add("&eNow is %time")
                .add("&6Thanks for playing on that server!")
                .add("&cHave fun guys! %motd");

        ArrayNode firstArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        firstArrayNode.add(firstObjectNode);

        ArrayNode secondArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        secondArrayNode.add(secondObjectNode);

        ObjectNode principalObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        principalObjectNode.putPOJO("mechanic", firstArrayNode);

        ObjectNode secondarObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        secondarObjectNode.putPOJO("messages", secondArrayNode);

        arrayNode.add(principalObjectNode);
        arrayNode.add(secondarObjectNode);

        if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(arrayNode);
        }

        /*String json = file.toString();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
        String messages = jsonNode.get("messages").asText();
        String mechanic = jsonNode.get("mechanic").asText();
        System.out.println("Messages: " + messages + "\n\n\n" + "Mechanic: " + mechanic + "\n\n");*/
        //ObjectConfig config = new ObjectConfig(messages, mechanic);
        //objectMapper.writeValue(new File(SimpleMessagesAPI.getMainAPI().getDataFolder() + "config.json"), config);

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is JSON what I want to create:

```js
{
  "mechanic": {
    "period"          : 5,
    "async"           : true,
    "country"         : "Europe/Bucharest"
  },
  "messages": {
    "broadcast"       : [
      "&7Hello players! Now is %server_online players!",
      "&eNow is %time",
      "&6Thanks for playing on that server!",
      "&cHave fun guys! %motd"
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I executed the code, this created an empty JSON object, why?

And `file.createNewFile();` says "result is ignored".

Thanks so much for help guys

Comment: `objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(..)` Returns a string. This you should write to your file

Comment: fileWriter.write(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(..) ) still not work on this code.

Comment: You only write it if the file not exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code lines

```
file.createNewFile();
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(arrayNode);
```

1. You got a compiler warning on `file.createNewFile();` saying
   *result is ignored*, because you ignored the boolean result returned by
   `file.createNewFile()`.

   You better should do something like this:

   ```
   if (!file.createNewFile())
       throw new IOException("could not create file " + file);
   ```
2. Your method call [`.writeValueAsString(arrayNode)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)) just
   produces a JSON string, but it doesn't write this string to anywhere.

   You need to use [`.writeValue(file, arrayNode)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#writeValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Object)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a simpler way of creating json from structured data. You can create three class which represents your json structure. And you can simply initialize instance of objects and serialize it with ObjectMapper.

Here an alternative way :

```
package yourPackage;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public String serializeData() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MyJson json = new MyJson();
        Mechanic mechanic = new Mechanic();
        mechanic.setAsync(true);
        mechanic.setCountry("Europe/Bucharest");
        mechanic.setPeriod(5);

        Message message = new Message();
        List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(
                "&7Hello players! Now is %server_online players!",
                "&eNow is %time",
                "&6Thanks for playing on that server!",
                "&cHave fun guys! %motd");

        message.setBroadcast(messages);

        json.setMechanic(mechanic);
        json.setMessages(message);

        return mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
    }
}

@Data // comes from lombok
class MyJson {
    private Mechanic mechanic;
    private Message messages;
}

@Data
class Mechanic{
    private int period;
    private boolean async;
    private String country;
}

@Data
class Message {
    private List<String> broadcast;
}
```

Serialized output:

```
{
    "mechanic": {
        "period": 5,
        "async": true,
        "country": "Europe/Bucharest"
    },
    "messages": {
        "broadcast": [
            "&7Hello players! Now is %server_online players!",
            "&eNow is %time",
            "&6Thanks for playing on that server!",
            "&cHave fun guys! %motd"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can write to destionation file with the following line :

```
    Files.write(Paths.get("config.json"), serializeData().getBytes());
```

Maven for lombok:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you asking?

Comment: Edit: nothing, i fix

Comment: I added imports and maven dependency for lombok. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/iripavipes.cpp. Sorry for asking again, but can i ask you why i got empty file on that?

Comment: I added the write file method for one line code. You can change the file name. I serialize to file I tested it.

Comment: Output is pasted like that: https://hastebin.com/jemezupunu.json. I can't format array from "broadcast" to be exactly like how i pasted ?

Comment: @NicuGhergu your link is contains nothing. What is the problem?